# Put spinner on center of image container with CSS

Tags: html, css

Id like to put a spinner into center of the image container if no image 'foo.jpg' is present.

I have tried the next but no success

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pubqdzca/

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.drop-box-filled-totem {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border: 5px dashed #219;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /*padding: 50px 10px;*/
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" align="center">
    <div class="image-upload">
      <label for="file-input">
         <span> <img class="drop-box-filled-totem" 
            src="foo.jpg" 
             onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jpg') this.src='//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Carregando...</span>
         </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image immediately loaded for me: what exactly is the problem? That the spinner doesn't disappear? That he isn't on the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for an extra item container when all you need on that container is some css generated content. Create a surrounding container, and position the icon on the pseudo element `::after` using `left: 50%; top: 50%;` (here 50% corresponds to 50% of the surrounding container), then fix the mispositioning by issueing `transform(-50%, -50%)` (here the percentage refers to the icon, not the surrounding container).

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.drop-box-filled-totem {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border: 5px dashed #219;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.drop-box-filled-totem-container {
  position: relative;
}

.drop-box-filled-totem-container::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f110";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: ;
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin-center 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin-center 2s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fa-spin-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(359deg)translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
@keyframes fa-spin-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: rotate(359deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" align="center">
    <div class="image-upload">
      <label for="file-input" style="border: 1px solid red">
         <span class="drop-box-filled-totem-container"> <img class="drop-box-filled-totem" 
            src="foo.jpg" 
             onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jpg') this.src='//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'">
            <span class="sr-only">Carregando...</span>
         </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this you removed the spin effect

Comment: Thx for hinting me. Added it.

Comment: and in your case why adding all this CSS for the rotation :) since he's already using font awesome he can keep the use of the icon where everything is already defined ;)

Comment: Hi, Thank very much. Splendid solution.

Answer (score 3):

1. Declare `relative` positioning on a *containing element* of the icon
   in question, `.image-upload` should do fine.
2. Declare `absolute` positioning on the *nested icon element* then
   offset the position accordingly with `left`, `right`, `top` and
   `bottom` property values.
3. Declare a `max-height` equivalent to the `font-size` property value
   of the icon as well to negate the undesirable rotation of a full
   height element.

**Example:**

```
.image-upload {
  position: relative;
}

.image-upload .fa-spinner {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 14px;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.drop-box-filled-totem {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border: 5px dashed #219;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Additional */

.image-upload {
  position: relative;
}

.image-upload .fa-spinner {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" align="center">
    <div class="image-upload">
      <label for="file-input">
         <span> <img class="drop-box-filled-totem" 
            src="foo.jpg" 
             onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jpg') this.src='//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Carregando...</span>
         </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pubqdzca/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use position relative and set negative value to top. This is not a generic solution to center everything whatever the height/width is but it can be enough in your case.

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.drop-box-filled-totem {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border: 5px dashed #219;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

i.fa-spin {
  position:relative;
  top:-55px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" align="center">
    <div class="image-upload">
      <label for="file-input">
         <span> <img class="drop-box-filled-totem" 
            src="foo.jpg" 
             onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jpg') this.src='//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Carregando...</span>
         </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the height of the image triples?

Comment: @connexo we adjust the values :) as we can see in the CSS the height is specified fixed value so i guess no need to make a lot of CSS using % to center the element since the height is fixed. But of course a generic solution is always better, but if we can write less CSS for a specific case why not

Comment: So what if your get a remote image and you have no idea what dimensions it has? In the real world there's hardly anything worse than hard-coding values.

Comment: @connexo am totally aware about this :) i simply added this code to this situation .. the image has a height of 100px so whataver the image you will be using it will always be 100px in this case. so my code fit well this situtation and then it's a solution for the OP to understand the use of relative and negative values. This will never be a generic and best solution but in this case it works well.